# Origin of milquetoast and the negative meaning of milk in modern usage

Tags: meaning, etymology, connotation

I searched the word **milquetoast** and found out that it is a very pejorative term used in American English (after a cartoon character- Casper Milquetoast) to refer to someone of an unusually meek, bland, soft or submissive nature, who is easily overlooked, written off, and who may also appear overly sensitive, timid, indecisive or cowardly (Wikipedia);   the equivalent of a pipsqueak.

I’m quite taken aback and find it difficult to understand  the connection between the word **milk** - originally associated  with kindness  and humanness, namely in Shakespeare’s work (milk of human kindness  & milky gentleness )- and the negative  attributes mentioned above.

My questions are:

How did this shift in meaning occur, and what’s the connection between milk and the negative meaning  it acquired? Are there other words or expressions referring to the pejorative use of the word milk in English (American or other varieties of English)?

Milk of human kindness

Definition:

A phrase from Macbeth, by William Shakespeare, meaning humane feeling, concern for other people: “Everyone agreed that Houston was a brilliant thinker and an excellent lawyer, but some people worried that he lacked the milk of human kindness.”

Dictionary.com

Comment: Did you read the entire Wikipedia article, including the part about _milk and toast_?

Comment: Related: [Does milk toast, milk-toast, or milktoast mean the same as milquetoast?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159549/does-milk-toast-milk-toast-or-milktoast-mean-the-same-as-milquetoast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**milksop** is a very similar word, which Merriam-Webster defines as

> *a weak boy or man*

or

> *an unmanly man*

The etymology given is

> *Middle English, literally, bread soaked in milk. First Known Use: 14th century*

A Google search for *milksop* provides the synonyms:

> *namby-pamby, coward, weakling, Milquetoast*

I have found no firm agreement on whether the term *milksop* for a weak person derives from that person's similarity to the dish of milksop (bland, insipid, weak), or that the person resembles the sort of individual who would be fed milksop (an infant, or sickly person).  It is certainly one or the other.

There is a long discussion on the etymology of *milksop* in [**Current Methods in Historical Semantics**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0FsE8GftrJQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)(pages 26-29), which again reaches no firm conclusion on this matter, as far as my understanding of the passage goes.

However, it is certain that there is no development of *milk* itself as being a negative term.

Incidentally, *sop* itself appears to come from *soup* as indicated in [The Register of the Privy Council of Scotland, Volume 6 (1599-1604)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5Co5AQAAMAAJ&q=milk%20sop&dq=milk%20sop&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i6OrVPDdFtPpaLb-gbAL&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA), referring to a breakfast in 1602.

> Unless milk is implied in the “ sowpe” in which the “quhyte breid" *[white bread]* or the “ait laif” *[oat loaf]* was to be presented, there is no mention whatever of that article.  Porridge also, which we should have expected at the bursars' table, seems to be completely absent; for it is difficult to construe "ain ait laif in a sowpe" *[one oat loaf in a soup]* as meaning ordinary porridge even without milk. What we see is some kind of sop of oat bread for the bursars, and a similar sop of wheat bread for the masters, with cold meat and ale in addition.  On this they began the day in Glasgow in the year 1602, - the breakfast of the Glasgow Professors not differing much, it may be assumed from that on which Shakespeare and other well-remembered Englishmen of that time were in the habit of beginning the day in London.

This passage may suggest that the nature of the dish is what is referred to when milksop was first used as an insult, as bursars, masters and professors at Glasgow, in addition to Shakespeare and other London gentlemen would not take kindly to being considered sickly by dint of their choice of breakfast dish.  But, I concede that this is not proof and I consider the matter to be open to debate.

Comment: "milk soaked in bread is soft" - and hard to imagine ;)

Comment: I overlooked "toast"-- hard to imagine why.

Comment: I think that oerkelens's point is that you have "milk soaked in bread" where it might make more sense to say "bread soaked in milk."

Comment: Ah yes, I've corrected my confused typing.  Thanks, oerlekens and Sven.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the person being described is *like* bread soaked in milk, it's that they *eat* bread soaked in milk.

Milktoast was a common dish (recommended even by physicians of generations past) for those who were convalescing, or otherwise weak of constitution. Thus, a grown man who was weak, meek, sickly, etc., would be called a "milquetoast" or "milksop" - implying that he was too fragile to even tolerate a regular meal.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but do you have a reference for that, to add completeness to the answer?

Comment: Wikipedia: Milk toast, light and easy to digest, is an appropriate food for someone with a weak or "nervous" stomach.

Comment: Wikipedia has an entry for "Milk toast" describing it as a food commonly given to children or the sick. I can't think of the movie... (maybe, "Topper") where the henpecked husband is given milk toast, instead of the steak he wants, for dinner - (supposedly because he has an ulcer, or something) the gesture is meant to indicate that he's weak in spirit, and allows his wife to dominate him. Anyway, to me it's a funny question - the reference would be obvious to anyone over 70... Go ask Granny - she'll tell ya.

Comment: That still doesn't specify whether the insult derives from a person who can only eat milk toast, or a person that resembles milk toast in some way. In fact, wikipedia's entry states "Milk toast's soft blandness served as inspiration for the name of the timid and ineffectual comic strip character Caspar Milquetoast, drawn by H. T. Webster from 1924 to 1952. Thus, the term *milquetoast* entered the language as the label for a timid, shrinking, apologetic person."

Comment: Oh, good gravy... This reminds me of how I'm always explaining to kids how "Letting your freak flag fly" only meant (literally) growing your hair long - in the 1960's - when the expression was first coined. They refuse to believe me, (despite the fact that I have first-hand memories) because they prefer the new meaning. Yes, Phil, "milquetoast" entered the language in the way you describe. The cartoon character was NAMED "Milquetoast" BECAUSE of the expression "milk toast" to describe that type of character.

Comment: Here... will you accept "milksop"? "And who doth lead them but a paltry fellow, / Long kept in Brittany at our mother's cost, / A milksop, one that never in his life / Felt so much cold as overshoes in snow? --William Shakespeare, Richard III" (courtesy of Conservapedia)

Comment: I'm not arguing with you about meaning in the slightest.  Incidentally, until I started researching this I'd never heard of the word "milquetoast" or the cartoon character.  I've also never heard the expression "letting your freak flag fly", so I don't even know that the "new meaning" of that is.  Anyway, all I'm saying is that nothing you've said (apart from your own opinion) illustrates whether milksop (or milquetoast) came to be a description of a person via the nature of milksop itself or the nature of a person who could only eat milksop.

Comment: I can't understand how describing someone as RESEMBLING an obscure foodstuff seems to make sense to people. (White and mushy?) Why not use "mashed potatoes" - which is something more familiar? BECAUSE before Gerber started putting baby food in little jars, milk toast was a common "first food" to give a baby. If you were very ill, Mama might make you some to comfort you - since you couldn't seem to conjure an appetite. Now, if Mama didn't want you to grow up and be a man, she would continue to serve you milk toast, to preserve your mindset that you were still her itty-bitty baby.

Comment: (Cont.) THEREFORE, a "milk toast", or "milksop" or "milquetoast", is a "MAMA'S BOY" - with all the other characteristics of a man who has been suppressed by an overbearing or overprotective mother. (Submissive, frail, cowardly, etc,) I just can't believe that something this obvious is cause for debate. (Not that I mind debating, particularly.) "PRESUMABLY" is the only reference given for the alternate explanation - why does it seem more plausible? (I wanna punch whomever "presumed" in the nose, at this point.)

Comment: I know, I presumed one thing, you presumed another. Neither of us has a reference, which is what this site is all about. So I want to improve my answer, not get punched in (I'd say "on") the nose :-)  Also, because I'm sadder than sad, I feel foolishly compelled to mention that mashed potatoes weren't around when "milksop" came into use :-)

Comment: Also, I've edited my answer to take out my presumption.